# Suggestion required resolving an issue with query

Tags: mysql

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id
FROM collection_content_mappings Inner Join tbl_content_commons ON     collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id = tbl_content_commons.id 

INNER JOIN tbl_content_additionals ON collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id =   tbl_content_additionals.content_content_code 

WHERE collection_content_mappings.collection_id = 1
```

This part is the problem:

```
collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id = tbl_content_additionals.content_content_code
```

The field "collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id" is not the one that need to be equated there; instead I have to take `tbl_content_commons.content_common_code from tbl_content_commons where collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id = tbl_content_commons.id` . How do I add this to the query above?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have tagged this with three different dbms'. which is it?

Comment: Fixed your tags for ya :)

Answer (score 1):

You should really rename your tables when you are building the query.
I don't know if I understand properly what you want, but I think that is something like this:

```
    SELECT tbl_content_commons.id
    FROM tbl_content_commons
    Inner Join collection_content_mappings ON                         collection_content_mappings.tbl_content_common_id = tbl_content_commons.id 
    INNER JOIN tbl_content_additionals  ON tbl_content_additionals.content_content_code  = tbl_content_commons.content_common_code 
    WHERE tbl_content_commons.id = 1
```

Comment: what if I need to get values from tbl_content_additionals also using the same query